# A loosely-typed indexOf()?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let's suppose I have the array:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Now let's suppose I want to know the first index of a value that `==`s (not `===`s) a given value, like "3". For this case I would want to return 2, but Array.indexOf returns -1.

:(

Answer (score 6):

**Update 2021-04-13**: ES6 introduced [findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) and arrow functions, so you can now do...

```js
> [1,2,3,4].findIndex(v => v == '3')
2
```

---

[Original answer]

Well, there's the naive implementation ...

```
function looseIndex(needle, haystack) {
  for (var i = 0, len = haystack.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (haystack[i] == needle) return i;
  }
  return -1;
}
```

E.g.

```
> [0,1,2].indexOf('1')
-1  // Native implementation doesn't match
> looseIndex('1', [0, 1, 2])
1   // Our implementation detects `'1' == 1`
> looseIndex('1', [0, true, 2])
1   // ... and also that `true == 1`
```

(One bonus of this approach is that it works with objects like `NodeList`s and `argument`s that may not support the full Array API.)

If your array is sorted, you can do a binary search for better performance.  See [Underscore.js' sortedIndex code](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html) for an example

Comment: Another bonus is that it works in more browsers without a "shim" for *indexOf*. :-)

Answer (score 5):

[indexOf does strict equals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Compatibility), so do a conversion on either of the sides, You can try this way:

Either:

```
arr.map(String).indexOf("3");
```

or

```
var str = "3";
arr.indexOf(+str);
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JmaML/)**

Comment: This isn't doing an `==` comparison. It's still an identity comparison, just coercing the type, which isn't quite the same thing.

Comment: @broofa of course not. It just does convert the types as mentioned in my answer.

Comment: 'Just pointing out that casting to a specific type is not the same as doing `==`.  E.g. `true == 1`, but `String(true) == 'true'`. :-/

Comment: This is magic, thank you. It [also helped me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27895644).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
function getTypelessIndex(a, v) {
  return a.indexOf(String(v)) == -1)? a.indexOf(Number(v)) : array.indexOf(String(v));
}
```

But that may do `indexOf(String(v))` more than is desirable. To only do the index each way once at most:

```
function getTypelessIndex(a, v) {
  var index = a.indexOf(String(v));

  if (index == -1) {
    index = a.indexOf(Number(v));
  }
  return index;
}
```

Note that `Array.prototype.indexOf` is not supported in IE 9 and lower.