# toString() for each element of an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

I want to find whether an element, that might be a string OR a number, is inside an array. The array is `test` and the element is `value`. So far so good, I have this code:

```
function compare(value, test) {
  // We need to stringify all the values to compare them with a string
  return test.map(function(value){
    return value.toString();
    }).indexOf(value) > -1;
  }
alert(compare("2", [1, 2, 3]));
alert(compare("2", ["1", "2", "3"]));
```

**[It does work](http://jsfiddle.net/franciscop/b97x4vex/)**. However it looks devilish complex due to the fact that `indexOf()` [uses strict equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Description) which doesn't suit my needs. A *hacky* way would be doing the following, which also works:

```
return test.join("|").split("|").indexOf(value) > -1;
```

However it's simple to see that, if test is `["a", "b|c", "d"]` then we have a problem since we'd be comparing `a`, `b`, `c` & `d` instead of `a`, `b|c`, `d`. Finding a *safe character* is also not an option, so this solution is not valid. **Is there any easier way of doing an `indexOf()` with *normal equality*?**

Edit: my first attempt was doing this, which returned unexpectedly false from the strict equality and that's why I did it the complex way:

```
["1", "2", "3"].indexOf(2);
```

Comment: Your `compare` function looks fine to me, and not at all complex, and I don't see why you would need to change it ?

Comment: `arr.map(String).indexOf("3");` does it as seen in the original (:

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like the following?

```
function compare(value, test) {
  return test.indexOf(Number(value)) > -1 || 
        test.indexOf(String(value)) > -1;
}
alert(compare("2", [1, 2, 3]));
alert(compare("2", ["1", "2", "3"]));
```

Another way would be to use [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
function compare(value, test) {
  var num = Number(value),
      str = String(value);

  return test.some(function(val) {
    return val === num || val === str;
  });
}
alert(compare("2", [1, 2, 3]));
alert(compare("2", ["1", "2", "3"]));
```